# Utiliser le verbe « baser »

Tags: vocabulaire

Je voudrais savoir si j'utilise correctement le verbe « baser ».

Ma phrase est :

> Le gaullisme est un paquet de mesures politiques qui **est basé sur** les idées de de Gaulle.

Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cette phrase est bien correcte pour l'utilisation du verbe.

(Attention cela dit, il faut dire *les idées de **de** Gaulle*.)

Il est aussi possible d'utiliser la tournure pronominale du verbe, *se baser*, ce qui donnerait : *Le gaullisme est un paquet de mesures politiques qui **se base** sur les idées de De Gaulle*.

Des synonymes utilisables : *fonder*/*se fonder*, *s'inspirer* (le sens est cependant plus faible que *se baser*)...

Comment: Et pour plus de détails: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baser

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour m'aider!  J'assume que 'de' est de part du nom de 'de Gaulle'?  @PaulPicard

Comment: Tout à fait ! Dès qu'il y a des noms de ce type (Charles de Gaulle, Geneviève de Fontenay, etc.), on conserve le "de" lorsqu'on veut insérer le nom de famille dans une phrase.

Comment: Ah, je comprends ; merci :).